# Conditional @import in vanilla CSS?

Tags: css, import, conditional-statements

I just want to insert a sort of a variable in my CSS, to control where should I import resources from. Can I do something in the spirit of the following pseudocode (as far as I know, CSS does not have `@if` conditional statement):

```css
    :root { /* CSS variables, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70559286 */
      --import-local: 0;
    }
    @if(var(--import-local)) {
        @import url(codemirror.min.css);
        @import url(abbott.min.css);
    } else {
        @import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/codemirror.min.css);
        @import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/theme/abbott.min.css);
    }
```

Interestingly, this code does not seem to raise any errors in JavaScript console - but it does not seem to work either.

Note: this example not the best, since in principle one could just put the `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7` portion of the URL in a variable - but imagine that there's a lot more than just two entries, and  all of these entries have unique URLs (in that case, I'd find a variable for each and every URL tedious to manage - so I'd rather have one variable to switch between local and remote, and otherwise have the remotes written in verbatim).

So, is there anything I could use in vanilla CSS, to achieve conditional import based on a "switch" variable?